# Is this set $S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 − y^2 < 1\} $path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

How to prove problems like this I only know 2 steps

(1)make $f(t)$ and $f(0)=(x_1,y_2), f(1)=(x_2,y_2)$

(2)try to prove $f(t)$ is in $S$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: First step: draw a picture of the set. Second step: do you know what convexity is?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Here's another approach.  See whether you can prove that every point within the set is path-connected to a particular point within the set.  Because any two points that are path-connected to the same point are necessarily also path-connected to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The locus $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ is a hyperbola and

$$
S = \{(x,y): x^2-y^2<1\}
$$
is the region bounded by the hyperbola and containing $0$, as shown below:

[image: x^2 - y^2 = 1 is a hyperbola].

Clearly, this region is path-connected.

We can also explicitly write the path joining $(0, 0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)\in S$, that is the straight line segment joining those two points.
$$
\gamma : [0, 1] \to S
$$
$$
\gamma(t) = (tx_0, ty_0)
$$
This is well-defined because because $(tx_1)^2 - (ty_1)^2 = t^2(x_1^2 -y_1^2) < t^2 \le 1$.